# Chart.js - Line data on the chart do not match their dates

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

The data and dates for the white line in the chart you see below are as follows. As you can see here, for example, there is no data for March 9 - March 10 - March 11 and March 12. But since the white line comes to the left, when I hover the chart, it seems like there is data for March 10 as an example. How can I match data and date?

Date: [
"Apr 02 2023, 12:04",
"Apr 01 2023, 12:04",
"Mar 31 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 30 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 29 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 27 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 26 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 24 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 13 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 08 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 06 2023, 12:03",
"Mar 05 2023, 12:03"
]

Value: [
"0.0177",
"0.41",
"0.301",
"0.1",
"0.016",
"0.0171",
"0.0176",
"0.0175",
"0.0169",
"0.0101",
"0.0179",
"0.09"
]

[image]

I searched for fix this problem ut i can't find any solutions

Comment: `How can I match data and date?` depends on what chart you are using and how it’s configured.

Comment: Could you please add sandbox example for your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to adjust interaction options, see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#interactions). To achieve what I think is your desired behavior, you'll have to set:

- `options.interaction.axis` to 'x'
- `options.interaction.intersect` to false
- and leave `options.interaction.mode`: 'nearest' (default)

Here's a small snippet with one data point "missing" from each dataset:

```js
const chartData = [{
    label: "Avg. Price",
    type: "line",
    borderColor:'#fff',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    data: [
        {
            date: new Date("3/08/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 21.2,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/09/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 23.2,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/11/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 13.5,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/12/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 15,
        }
    ]
},
{
    label: "Floor Price",
    type: "line",
    borderColor:'#a4d',
    backgroundColor:'#a4d',
    data: [
        {
            date: new Date("3/08/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 11.2,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/10/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 12.1,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/11/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 23,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/12/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 21,
        }
    ]
},
{
    label: "Volume",
    type: "bar",
    backgroundColor: '#00d',
    data: [
        {
            date: new Date("3/08/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 14,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/09/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 19,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/10/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 17,
        },
        {
            date: new Date("3/11/2023").valueOf(),
            value: 15,
        }
    ]
}];


new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
    data: {
        datasets: chartData
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        parsing: {
            xAxisKey: "date",
            yAxisKey: "value",
        },
        interaction: {
            intersect: false,
            axis: 'x',
            //mode: 'nearest',
        },

        scales: {
            x: {
                type: "time",
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    displayFormats: {
                        day: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="height:120vh">
<canvas id="chart" style="background-color: #000"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-vCUbejtS+HcWYtDHRF2T5B0BKwVG/CLeuew5uT2AiX4SJ2Wff52+kfgONvtdATqkqQMC9Ye5K+Td0OTaz+P7cw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns"></script>
```

Comment: Hello @kikon. Firstly thank you for interesting. I tried your recommend. I created new array with my data (array example: https://jsfiddle.net/4s3p8dwa/1/). But i can see only 2 date in my chart like this https://ibb.co/kSf85cb . Can you help me ? :(

Comment: Sure, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16svgbot/1/) that corrects some minor mismatches and disables the code that uses the undefined `selectedDate`; If you want to test this with data for the other datasets, please fork from this fiddle, do changes step by step, and keep the resulting fiddle working without errors in the console if possible - this helps me identify the issues much easier.

Comment: thank you for recommend. I tried your recommend and thats work but line values are nested like this https://jsfiddle.net/9wdakjtr/1/

Comment: That's because you put all data in the same `riskArray` and from there to the "Risk" dataset, and there's no data in the other categories "Opportunity" and "Floor". I think some of the data points are not "Risk" values, but probably belong to the other datasets/categories.  Don't you have them split by categories or maybe you have a system by which each data point is "sent" to one or the other category?